# Calculation state is showing as Pending when it should be done

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have built an application that opens an Excel Template from Access. Everything was working wonderfully until I introduced linked pictures in my Excel Templates.

The entire application which used to execute in a few seconds now takes close to a minute to do only such simple things as write data from Access to Excel.

The reason for this is that Excel gets stuck in `CalculationStatus = Pending` probably because I'm using volatile functions for my linked pictures (offset).

Microsoft is aware of this issue and has kindly documented it along with their "resolution" [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028670)... which is essentially nothing.

**Does anyone else have an idea how to resolve or work around this issue?** I have tried changing my template and not using linked pictures but these solutions don't work very well / are cumbersome.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried the various solutions that were proposed in the comments. None have worked yet. After having eliminated those options I am essentially at the point where I see that as long as the worksheet contains a linked picture, this bug rears its ugly head.

I'll leave the question open in case someone else does have a workaround.

My own solution for the time being is that I'll be writing code to update the relevant cells using VBA.

Comment: Formulas with `OFFSET` can sometimes be replaced with `INDEX` - `MATCH` formulas. Those are not volatile.

Comment: Thank you Axel! You got me thinking in the right direction! I can't use `INDEX - MATCH` because I'm referring to an entire region and not a single cell, but I can try to do the same thing using `INDIRECT`. `INDIRECT` is also volatile, but I used that function in my template before the error appeared, so maybe it will work... i'll report back!

Comment: I'll bet you a doughnut it can be achieved with the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

Comment: Just tried using `INDIRECT`. Still not working.

Comment: @Jeeped Can you show me an example of how to return an array using `Index Match`?

Comment: Please show your `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` then we'll possible show you the `INDEX` replacement.

Comment: @AxelRichter My `OFFSET` and my `INDIRECT` were both named formulas (Formula Manager) that consisted in part of other named formulas... here is the `OFFSET` version: `=OFFSET(Rpt!$AA$26;1;getCountPos;6;1)` The formulas are always stored in the formula manager as this is the only way to get linked pictures to become dynamic.

Comment: Off the top of my head, `=INDEX(Rpt!$AA:$AAA; 27; getCountPos):INDEX(Rpt!$AA:$AAA; 32; getCountPos)` but **getCountPos** might have some bearing on the validity and that is apparently a super-secret.

Comment: I attempted yet another workaround... this time using INDEX: `=INDEX(nfLegend;1;getCountCcy+1)`. I shoved all the data in one cell so that I could use Index, but the application is still stuck in `Pending` when I run it.

Comment: @Jeeped Nope, getCountPos is the count of the position that I need to refrence. In the example it returns a number between 1 and 6. I thought the name was self explanatory. Index didn't work for me either ... i'll look into your formula anyway though as I want to see how it works with arrays. Any other ideas how to solve this conundrum?